# Why does JVM JIT compiler not compile a method if there is a breakpoint present in the method?

Tags: compilation, jvm, jit

The JIT compiler does not compile a method with breakpoints in it. What is the reason behind this ?

Comment: What are you referring to, exactly?

Answer (score 0):

Ever tried to debug a program compiled with `gcc -O3`? You will quickly see that it's futile - values of variables change without reason, the executed line of code jumps around like crazy and so on (there's a reason people still debug assembly code in these situations)

Now if you're debugging a method, you're certainly not interested in the speed of the debugged code, so you don't win anything from running compiled instead of interpreted code, but get a whole lot of problems from it - much easier this way.